# Any advice for Beginner Programmer studying Deep Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Thanks for making it this far on my post!
I am studying engineering, yet have a passion for programming and wish to implement computer science knowledge into my own research.

My question is pertaining to any resources that this community has available and any advice you all are willing to give regarding getting started in this broad field.

I’m mainly confused about ‘neural networks’ in relation to Deep Learning as well as implementation of algorithms.

I have slight Python and R knowledge.

Comment: Advice for starting here at Stack Overflow: read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And keep always in mind that this is not a forum, so open discussions, opinion-based questions, and general advice seeking are definitely off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: one of the subfora of StackExchange is probably a better fit for this question.

In any case, for ML you can do just fine with basic Python/R. Most of the research and work done on ML is based on TensorFlow and similar frameworks currently (2018). To use the frameworks you don't really need a strong programming background to setup and train models on them (although it certainly helps). Actually, math/statistics will help you more, specially if you want to get to the bottom of it (i.e. reading the latest articles/papers, etc.).

> Mainly I’m confused about ‘neural networks’ in relation to Deep Learning

"Deep Learning" is basically taking advantage of modern computing capabilities to train complex models (e.g. neural networks with many hidden layers) which a few years ago (e.g. 10 years ago) were unfeasible. Informally speaking, the more complex your network is, the more interesting are the things that it can learn.

> as well as implementation of algorithms.

Typically, you will use an existing framework -- you won't implement the algorithms yourself. Although, of course, implementing a MultiLayer Perceptron by yourself is always a good and fun learning exercise.